# How to match multiple (N) spaces in regex's lookarounds?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex `(?<={% start %}).*?(?={% end %})` that matches everything between two custom tags.

The problem is that if there are spaces inside tags (e.g., "{%      start %}") and I add `\s+?` condition, regex fails. The following code does not work: `(?<={%\s+?start\s+?%}).*?(?={%\s+?end\s+?%})` and I'm getting an error in PHP:

```
preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 25
```

The same regex works if I remove lookahead/lookbehind: `({%\s+?(start|end)\s+%})`.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you have some sample text?

Comment: Depending of the language, lookbehind can't be variable length.

Comment: Here's the sample text: http://pastebin.com/AUX1hd2T I also updated my question with the error message. I'm using PHP.

Comment: Don't use lookarounds. If you wan't the content between the tags use capturing groups. Eg: `start_regex(.*?)end_regex`

Comment: His answer is exactly that, to not use lookarounds (altho it has a lot of crap in it). It's completely unnecessary to use lookarounds in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

Try this [permlink](http://regex101.com/r/pD4aX5)

```
[{]%\s*?\b([^}]*start[^}]*)\b\s*?%[}]\s*?\b(.*?)\b\s*?[{]%\s*\b([^}]*end[^}]*)\b\s*%[}]
```

This will match all text inside your `{%` and `%}` brackets, and will automatically trim the text before putting the value into their groups.

Group 0 gets the entire matching string

1. gets the start tag text
2. gets the inner text
3. gets the end tag text

[image]

## Disclaimer

This will probably have some edge cases where the regex will fail if you have complex data nested into sub, if so then using regex would probably not be the best tool for this task.

## Summary

```
[{]%\s*?\b([^}]*start[^}]*)\b\s*?%[}]\s*?\b(.*?)\b\s*?[{]%\s*\b([^}]*end[^}]*)\b\s*%[}]
Char class [{] matches one of the following chars: {
% Literal `%`
\s 0 to infinite times [lazy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
1st Capturing group ([^}]*start[^}]*) 
Negated char class [^}] infinite to 0 times matches any char except: }
start Literal `start`
Negated char class [^}] infinite to 0 times matches any char except: }
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
\s 0 to infinite times [lazy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
% Literal `%`
Char class [}] matches one of the following chars: }
\s 0 to infinite times [lazy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
2nd Capturing group (.*?) 
. 0 to infinite times [lazy] Any character (except newline) 
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
\s 0 to infinite times [lazy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
Char class [{] matches one of the following chars: {
% Literal `%`
\s infinite to 0 times Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
3rd Capturing group ([^}]*end[^}]*) 
Negated char class [^}] infinite to 0 times matches any char except: }
end Literal `end`
Negated char class [^}] infinite to 0 times matches any char except: }
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
\s infinite to 0 times Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 
% Literal `%`
Char class [}] matches one of the following chars: }
```

## PHP example

with sample text
`{% start %} this is a sample text 1 {% end %}{% start %} this is a sample text 2 {% end %}`

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/[{]%\s*?\b([^}]*start[^}]*)\b\s*?%[}]\s*?\b(.*?)\b\s*?[{]%\s*\b([^}]*end[^}]*)\b\s*%[}]/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {% start %} this is a sample text 1 {% end %}
            [1] => {% start %} this is a sample text 2 {% end %}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => start
            [1] => start
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is a sample text 1
            [1] => this is a sample text 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => end
            [1] => end
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need regex to match text between the tags, not inside.

Comment: Edited response to satisify

Comment: Thanks, but PHP doesn't seem to take it. You can test it here: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm (use PCRE and PREG_MATCH_ALL).

Comment: Using sample text `{%    start %}some random text{% end %}` on your site with preg_match_all showed that there were the correct number of capture groups but there seems to be a problem with the site where the captured text isn't getting displayed. Running this on http://www.myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab  with the same options worked as expected. I've also updated my answer with a php example with output sample. I'm also using the case insensitive option.

Comment: Thank you! I must have tried your older regex. The updated answer works. P.S. This is one mad regex.